# Checking if the user inputs the same string twice using array

Tags: c#, arrays

i want to check if the user inputs a same string twice using array. don't have any idea on what codes to use can you suggest anything?

if the user inputs "1A" twice i want to print "Already Taken", and if the user enter a string which is not in my Array(arr) i want to print "invalid input"

this is my array

```
      string[,] arr = new string[,]
        {
            {"1A","2A","3A","4A","5A"},
            {"1B","2B","3B","4B","5B"},
            {"1C","2C","3C","4C","5C"},
            {"1D","2D","3D","4D","5D"},
        };
```

Comment: linq will be a good start

Comment: You'll have to give some sample input/output, the question is not very clear

Comment: @DorCohen that really doesn't sound like a LINQ question; I genuinely have no clue what the OP *is* trying to do, but I'm still pretty confident that LINQ isn't the first tool to pick up

Comment: @Josh you haven't given us any context as to how the array relates to the user's input... is the question here "the user must select two different values that are in the array"?. Or is it "the array represents the user's input; the values must be distinct"?

Comment: @MarcGravell take a look on my answer, I think that's what he meant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `HashSet<string>` to check if there are duplicates:

```
var set = new HashSet<string>();
bool noDuplicate = arr.Cast<string>().All(set.Add);
```

Comment: very tidy implementation

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Set`, e.g. `HashSet<String>`:

```
  HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet<string>();

  foreach(var item in arr)
    if (!hs.Add(item)) {
      // User used "item" at least twice
      break; 
    }
```

Comment: btw; you can simplify to just `if(!hs.Add(item)) { /* fail */ }` - this avoids doing a separate `Contains`/`Add` test per item.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using LINQ, something like this:

```
var query = arr.GroupBy(x=>x)
              .Where(g=>g.Count()>1)
              .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
  HashSet<String> hash = new HashSet<string>();

  string input = "TEST";
  bool found = false;

  foreach(string item in arr)
  {
      if (item.Equals(input))
      {
          if (hash.Contains(item))
          {
              Console.WriteLine("Already Taken");
          }
          else
          {
              hash.Add(item);
          }
          found = true;
          break;
      }
   }

  if (!found)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input");
  }
```